# How to work with dependent fields in Spring 3.0?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I tried to create my first spring mvc application. I'm using architecture: Spring MVC-Service-DAO-Persistence Architecture.
I've get this error:

```
Field error in object 'rooms' on field 'roomTypeId': rejected value [7]; codes    [typeMismatch.rooms.roomTypeId,typeMismatch.roomTypeId,typeMismatch.mypackage.domain.RoomType,typeMismatch]; arguments 
[org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes   [rooms.roomTypeId,roomTypeId]; arguments []; default message [roomTypeId]]; 
default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type   'mypackage.domain.RoomType' 
for property 'roomTypeId'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required  type [mypackage.domain.RoomType] for property 
'roomTypeId': no matching editors or  conversion strategy found]
```

Domain:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "rooms")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Rooms.findAll", query = "SELECT r FROM Rooms r")})
public class Rooms implements Serializable {
...
@JoinColumn(name = "RoomTypeId", referencedColumnName = "RoomTypeId")
@ManyToOne
private RoomType roomTypeId;
...
public RoomType getRoomTypeId() {
    return roomTypeId;
}
public void setRoomTypeId(RoomType roomTypeId) {
    this.roomTypeId = roomTypeId;
}     
}
```

Controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/room/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addRoom(@ModelAttribute("rooms") Rooms room,
        BindingResult result) {
    roomService.addRoom(room);
    return "redirect:/rooms";
}
```

I tried:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/room/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addRoom(@ModelAttribute("rooms") Rooms room, @RequestParam Long roomTypeId,
        BindingResult result) {
    room.setRoomTypeId(typeService.getType(roomTypeId.intValue()));
    roomService.addRoom(room);
    return "redirect:/rooms";
}
```

jsp:

```xml
<form:form method="post" action="room/add" commandName="room">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="name">
                <spring:message code="label.roomname" />
            </form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="roomTypeId">
                <spring:message code="label.typeroom" />
            </form:label>

        </td>
        <td>
            <form:select path="roomTypeId" name="roomTypeId"> 
                <c:forEach items="${typeList}" var="type">
                    <form:option value="${type.roomTypeId}" label="${type.name}"/>
                </c:forEach>
            </form:select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit"
                               value="<spring:message code="label.addroom"/>" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form:form>
```

I understand why this shows me. But I do not know how to fix it. Help me fix it or tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Before you continue, in `public String addRoom(@ModelAttribute("rooms") Rooms room, @RequestParam Long roomTypeId, BindingResult result...`, put the `BindingResult` argument next to the `Rooms` argument.

Answer (score 0):

In the following method declaration

```
public String addRoom(@ModelAttribute("rooms") Rooms room, @RequestParam Long roomTypeId, BindingResult result...,
```

put the `BindingResult` argument next to the `Rooms` argument.